# how to set production environment variables in django

Tags: django, environment-variables

I am having some trouble setting environment variables in my production environment, I have some logic in django settings that depends on it. I have tried exportng it through variouse places '/etc/profile, ~.bashrc, etc'

The problem is that those only set them when there is a login (I believe?) But if I navigate a browser to the server I can see that the variable was not set correctly through the debug. I am running django1.7/gunicorn/nginx. I suspected to put it in the gunicorn /etc/init/gunicorn.conf but that did not work.

How can I set this?

Comment: You could set them in the WSGI file.

Comment: would setting them in the wsgi file affect my local environment too? I want it to only affect the production

Comment: You could add some logic that adds the environment vars on when it's prod, as it's a regular Python file.

Comment: ok I am not sure exactly what to add to it to check if its on prod. The wsgi file isn't run on the devserver though, right?

Comment: I usually use os.environ.get() in the settings.py to get environment variables. .get() lets you set a sane default with the second parameter too :)

Comment: Hmmmm, never mind, I think you want to set environment variables, not get them. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You could set them in the WSGI file. –  Simeon Visser

Thanks, this solved my problem for my purposes. I don't believe that the wsgi file runs on the dev server so it worked perfectly and only set the variable on the production. Thanks